# Events and parms from cmp to controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

Im new here so let me send my Hi to all community.

I'm trying with Lightning and all looks great!, have my component and app working, basically my component gets a list of Contacts and display it.

Now I want to give some events to the items, so I add a ui:button on each item of my list, and I want to call to an action in the controller and here is my issue, any way to send the Contact.Id of the selected item to the controller? i cant find documentation about it.

Thanks in advance.

CODE:

Component

```xml
<aura:component controller="okty.Contacts">
    <aura:attribute name="contacts" type="Contact[]"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    
    <ul>
        <aura:iteration var="cont" items="{!v.contacts}">
            <li>
                <span>{!cont.Name}</span> 
                <ui:button label="Add Task" attribute="" press="{!c.addNewTask}" />
            </li>
        </aura:iteration>
    </ul>
    
</aura:component>
```

Controller

```javascript
({
    doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
        console.info("call to doInit and Helper is:");
        console.info(helper);
        helper.getContacts(component);
    },
    
    addNewTask: function(component, event, helper) {
        console.info(component);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i answer my own question. if anybody have the same issue.

You must create a component like that:

```xml
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="cont" type="Contact"/>
    <li>
        <span>{!v.cont.Name}</span> 
        <ui:button label="Add Task" press="{!c.getContactInfo}"/>
    </li>
</aura:component>
```

Also, a controller for the component with the action of the button:

```javascript
({
    getContactInfo : function(component, event, helper) {
        alert(component.get("v.cont.Name"));
    }
})
```

Then on iteration you call this component:

```xml
<aura:iteration var="cont" items="{!v.contacts}">
    <okty:contactIterationItem cont="{!cont}"/>
</aura:iteration>
```

And its all, you have a "click" action for each item in the list.